# I can't install cypress recorder by terminal in vscode

Tags: cypress, recorder

I have npm version 10.2.0 and cypress  version 13.3.1 and when I try to install cypress recorder with the command

```
npm install cypress-recorder -D
```

the terminal gives me the error

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cypress-recorder - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'cypress-recorder@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.`
```

I tried to use

```
yarn add cypress-recorder -D
```

but it didn't work by giving me the same error.

What can I do?

Comment: Hey vram, if you are having trouble getting Cypress runner to see installed Chrome browser, you can add Chrome Dev as a second choice.

Comment: I notice that Edge requires extensions to be approved by Microsoft before they can be installed, so you can ask Cypress (via github issue) to gain certification for their extension.

Answer (score 2):

It's one of two things -

- [cypress-io/cypress-recorder-extension](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-recorder-extension)
- [webstore/detail/cypress-recorder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cypress-recorder/glcapdcacdfkokcmicllhcjigeodacab)

Both are extensions, not npm packages. You will need to add them to the chrome browser.

Comment: Thanks but I'm using microsoft edge, for some reason cypress doesn't detects chrome, I applied all the solutions found in cypress github site but none of them worked. So I need to know how to do it in edge. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: You'd have to ask Cypress about that, perhaps it needs an enhancement - log on to Github and raise an issue against the project. If it's already possible to use with Edge, they will tell you.

Comment: Clearly, you can't treat an extension as an npm package.

Comment: I think I've done that, I tried it but I couldn't install it as an npm package, see the original post